# How can I get previous row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have query:

```
SELECT ID
FROM VACANCIES 
WHERE CATEGORYID = 1
AND VISIBLE = '1'
AND user_enable = '1'
AND DATA >= '2012-08-10 10:54:46'
AND torder >= 0
AND ID > 570153
ORDER BY torder ASC, DATA ASC, ID ASC
LIMIT 1
```

I get the result ID - 570164 as previous key and this is wrong result: correct result is 567556

```
570164 | ROW 1 | 2012-08-10 11:27:39
567556 | ROW 2 | 2012-08-10 10:55:53
570153 | ROW 2 | 2012-08-10 10:54:46
```

Is there a solution to get prev id ? 
Notice: 
I make order by date but date can be equal and prev id can be less than curent ID

Answer (score 0):

Your condition states that the ID must be greater than 570153.

- 570164 is the result returned, which satisfies that condition.
- 567556 is the result you're hoping for, which doesn't satisfy that condition.

My guess is you want a less than rather than greater than on your ID condition, but I don't know what you're aiming for so can't be sure.
I'd also switch your sort condition from ASC to DESC on the ID column, or you'll get the first match (i.e. lowest id) rather than the one closest to the value you're comparing to.

```
SELECT ID
FROM VACANCIES 
WHERE CATEGORYID = 1
AND VISIBLE = '1'
AND user_enable = '1'
AND DATA >= '2012-08-10 10:54:46'
AND torder >= 0
AND ID < 570153
ORDER BY torder ASC, DATA ASC, ID DESC
LIMIT 1
```